# Do I need a transit visa for layover in Italy?

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, transit, iraqi-citizens

I am flying from Chicago to Istanbul and my flight will layover in Rome for an hour and a half. I am holding a US green card and am traveling with Iraqi passport. I am not sure if I will require an Italian transit visa or will I be fine since am not leaving the transit area? I tried the Italy embassy support line and they keep telling me to check the website and there was not a clear answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

From this [page](http://www.esteri.it/mae/en/ministero/servizi/stranieri/ingressosoggiornoinitalia/visto_ingresso/paesi_soggetti_visto_transito_aeroportuale.html), it would seem that you do not need an transit visa to transit in Italy.

Comment: This answer seems correct, why -1?